# Couchbase 2.0 and php5.4

Tags: php, couchbase

Is anyone using couchbase 2.0 with PHP 5.4? I ask because the PECL libraries for PHP appear to not support PHP5.4's new interfaces. This is a real bummer as I'd really like to start taking advantage of 5.4's support for `JsonSerializable` which would appear to be a nice compliment to folks living in the JSON world of Couchbase.

Comment: I have experimented with the above combo on my localmachine, although without the PECL libraries... Is there a question somewhere in here? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used PHP 5.4.x, specifically I used the Bitnami MAPP stack, which comes with the couchbase.so already built for 5.4 (although you can do that yourself easily from the source). Then connected it to my local Couchbase instance (in my case I used the Laravel framework).

**My Blog**: http://blog.couchbase.com/easy-php-couchbase-setup-mac-bitnami
But now the couchbase.so is already in the Bitnami stack... so you can skip that part.

**Bitnami MAPP**: http://bitnami.com/stack/mapp

**Bitnami MAMP**: http://bitnami.com/stack/mamp (also can be installed via Mac App Store)

Comment: Do you know of any good links to compiling couchbase.so manually? Also, I need to be able to ensure that I can fluidly switch between 5.3 and 5.4 on my development machine so whatever the process I need to avoid having PECL/PEAR getting confused (I'm assuming for now that PECL/PEAR would probably just be kept in the dark about the manually compiled 5.4 modules).

Comment: There instructions for that on my blog post, but you should really consider the Bitnami stack's, everything is self contained, so if you are using 5.4 under Bitnami, it's really simple, you just execute a sh file to update paths, and it has a console for starting and stopping services, super awesome.

Comment: Ok, i'll look at that.

Comment: BTW, what do you see as the big advantages of the bitnami MAPP stack versus MAMP (which I use)? Other than of course that it comes with couchbase.so for PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: No real difference, one has MySQL (MAMP) and the other Postgres (MAPP), either or is fine, and of course you don't have to start either of them up if you aren't using polyglot.